# Matlab download data from ftp site

Tags: matlab

I am trying to download all files from ftp site. There are not many files in there but they are under numerous layers of folders and subfolders.

I can recursively write a for loop looking at what the design path for each folder and subfolder is or is there a smarter way to achieve this.

Currently my code looks something as

```
clear; clc;
mw  =   ftp('pubftp.spp.org');
cd( mw, 'Markets' )
cd( mw, 'DA' )
cd( mw, 'LMP_By_SETTLEMENT_LOC' )
ftpDir  =   dir( mw );

for i = 1:length( ftpDir )
  cd( mw, ftpDir( i ).name );
  dir2    =   dir( mw );
  %.....
  %.....
end`
```

Is there a smarter way to download all files from the ftp location in the code above.

Comment: Use `wget` (can be called from within MATLAB using a `system` command if required).

Comment: Can you please show me example of implementation as I don't have that function in my older version of matlab?

Comment: It's not a MATLAB function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget ).

Comment: I opened the command line was able to ftp to the server but it says wget is not a valid command. I am on windows machine.

Comment: did you tried using wildcard character?